# Autocomplete keyboard input

Tags: jquery, validation, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete allowing the user to select a product by typing their code or name. Then the autocomplete fills hidden texts with certains atrtibutes.

It works great when the user needs help looking for an  unknown product. He type a partial name, select from the list and that´s it.

But when the product is known by their code (i.e. 9876 *variable lenght codes* , they want to type it, press tab* and continue. How can I accomplish that?

*(here I need to validate a unique code value and assign values with the autocomplete)

PS: In my own research, the change event allows me to know when, but I cant realize how to do that?

```
change: function (ev, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
      $("#txt").autocomplete("search", $("#txt").val());
      // if search return only one item in the selection, ui.item must charge with 
      // the result data and let me use it.
    ];
},
```

TIA,

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the datasource the autocomplete is using. My guess would be that you either need to change to autocomplete so it can search by name and by code. or add the autocomplete twice, once with the name datasource and once with the code datasource.

Comment: it's a bit unclear if code search already works and just need the tab functionality or needs both

Comment: Any autocomplete do the same: Typing an exact match criteria and pressing tab wont fire the select event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the search by `code` already works, the `TAB` functionality can be added with `autoFocus` option set to `true` in `autocomplete` initialization:

```
$( "#txt" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: 'autocomplete_source',
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#hidden').val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

`autoFocus` will make the first item to be automatically focused upon search, both keys `TAB` and `Enter` will select the item and advance.

Setting hidden fields with the value selected is also no hard task, just use the `select` event also in the demo code.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/9yV3t/1/

If you still need to make `code` search to work, a suggestion would be your datasource treating the data sent to search as both `product name` and `product code`

Comment: Hurray! autoFocus did the trick! Thank you VERY much. Now Im feel like is friday!

Comment: @user2934862 you're very welcome, I updated the answer with some more info about the `select` event, cheers